# Java: What is the best free library to plot polynomial graph?

Tags: library, java, graphs

I want to build a program to plot 2D polynomial graphs in Java to plot graph such as y=x^2. Any suggestions for a free library? Is there any free library which can do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints.

Comment: No personal experience, but a quick Google search suggests http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/